# how to convert milliseconds into HH:MM:SS format in mongodb(3.4 version)

Tags: string, mongodb, time, projection, milliseconds

I am projecting a field as i want the difference between DateOfOcurrance and current time. Then I want to compare the diff_time field with one time which is in String format(HH:MM:SS) as I want those documents which have less than 15mins diff_time, but not getting.

```
{$project: {diff_time:{ $subtract: ["$DateOfOcurrance", new Date("2020-02-14")]}}},
{"$match": {"diff_time": { "$lt": "00:15:00" }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates are stored as the number of milliseconds since epoch.  When you subtract one date from another, you get a NumberLong containing the difference in milliseconds.

To find differences less than 15 minutes, use:

```
{"$match": {"diff_time": { "$lt": 900000 }}}
```

(900000 = number of milliseconds in 15 minutes)